# android build variant: show java sources of all product flavors

Tags: android, android-productflavors

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        ...
    }

    productFlavors {
        demo {}
        full{}
    }
}
```

sources:

```
src/demo/java
src/full/java
```

Inside android studio, with android view, only the sources of one product flavor of currently selected build variant can be seen. Is there a way to see all source codes of all product flavors with android view?